# Splitting file based on pattern '\r\n00' in korn shell

Tags: shell, ksh

My file temp.txt looks like below

```
00ABC
PQR123400
00XYZ001234
012345
0012233
```

I want to split the file based on pattern '\r\n00'. In this case temp.txt should split into 3 files

```
first.txt: 
00ABC
PQR123400

second.txt
00XYZ001234
012345

third.txt
0012233
```

I am trying to use csplit to match pattern '\r\n00' but the debug shows me invalid pattern. Can someone please help me to match the exact pattern using csplit

Comment: First thing first THANKS for Good and clear question, keep it up. For `I am trying to use csplit to match pattern '\r\n00' ` Good that you have mentioned your efforts, please 
 also put them also in form of code in your question, cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`.

This code will create files with names like: `1.txt`, `2.txt` and so on in your system. This will also take care of closing output files in backend so that we don't get in-famous error `too many files opened` one.

```
awk -v RS='\r?\n00' -v count="1" '
{
  outputFile=(count++".txt")
  rt=RT
  sub(/\r?\n/,"",rt)
  if(!rt){
    sub(/\n+/,"")
    rt=prevRT
  }
  printf("%s%s\n",(count>2?rt:""),$0) > outputFile
  close(outputFile)
  prevRT=rt
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk -v RS='\r?\n00' -v count="1" '      ##Starting awk program from here and setting RS as \r?\n00 aong with that setting count as 1 here.
{
  outputFile=(count++".txt")            ##Creating outputFile which has value of count(increases each time cursor comes here) followed by .txt here.
  rt=RT                                 ##Setting RT value to rt here.
  sub(/\r?\n/,"",rt)                    ##Substituting \r?\n with NULL in rt.
  if(!rt){                              ##If rt is NULL then do following.
    sub(/\n+/,"")                       ##Substituting new lines 1 or more with NULL.
    rt=prevRT                           ##Setting preRT to rt here.
  }
  printf("%s%s\n",(count>2?rt:""),$0) > outputFile   ##Printing rt and current line into outputFile.
  close(outputFile)                     ##Closing outputFile in backend.
  prevRT=rt                             ##Setting rt to prevRT here.
}
'  Input_file                           ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Sorry I am very new to korn shell and I am not sure how to embed this in my korn shell program.

Comment: @Hane, Hey no worries. You can copy and paste my program and change only `Input_file` to your actual file then run it on terminal itself, try it out and then we will see how it goes, cheers.

Comment: yes that works, Thank you :) but how do I embed it in ksh file? plus I have to do more in terms of setting a dynamic file name which I want to extract from the lines in the file starting with '\r\n00' pattern, also check if the file exist then append to the existing file or else create a new file.

Comment: I am able to extract the dynamic file name but splitting part which you gave, I tried to embed in my ksh program but it doesnt work

Comment: @Hane, For running this code in shell script, `#!/bin/ksh`  at top of file and copy paste all code in it(make sure to change Input_file name to your actual file's name) and give proper permissions to your script(example `script.ksh`) and then run it, it should work then. I would say for your new 2 questions you can add a new post/question here.

Comment: somehow the code adds extra '00' in the beginning of the first record in the file

Comment: @Hane, Sure, have fixed that problem now, kindly do check it once and let me know how it goes, cheers.

Comment: Now the first record in the first file looks fine but the remaining files have  stripped '00' from their first record. eg first record is 0000111, 2nd record is 0000112. With the earlier code, the 1st rec became 000000111. with the new code 2nd rec became 00112

Comment: @Hane, Sorry to say but for me this code has worked fine and 2nd file named `2.txt` has first line like `00XYZ001234` in it and 3rd file 3.txt has first line like `0012233` in it. Which looks Good to me as per your shown samples, please do let me know on same.

Comment: Just changed the condition printf("%s%s\n",(count>=2?rt:""),$0) and it seems to work. Will test more and let you know. Thanks a ton for all the help!

Comment: @Hane, cheers and happy learning.

Comment: @Hane, just one request, update your failed `csplit` command in your question even it didn't work that's fine, so in case any user searches that in Google they should be benefited from it, cheers.